# Can see samba shares but not access them

Tags: permissions, security, windows-7, samba, file-sharing

For the life of me I cannot figure this one out.

I have samba installed and set up on the ubuntu box and on the Win7 box I CAN SEE all the shares I created.

I created two users on ubuntu that map to the users in windows.  On ubuntu they are both admins, user A & B on Windows User A is admin and user B is poweruser.

User A can see both shares and access them, but user B can see everythin, but only access the homes directory, the other directory throws an error.

I have two drives in Ubuntu and this is the smb.config file (I am new to samba):

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
wins support = no
dns proxy = yes
name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000

syslog = 0

panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
security = user

encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam

obey pam restrictions = yes

unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user
;   usershare max shares = 100
usershare allow guests = yes
```

And here is the share section:

Both user A & B can access this from windows.  No problems.

```
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
writable = yes
```

Both User A & B can see this share, but only user A can access it.  User B get an error thrown.

```
[stuff]
comment = Unixmen File Server
path = /media/data/appinstall/
browseable = yes
;writable = no
read only = yes
hosts allow =
```

The permission for the media/data/appinstall/ is as follows:

appInstall properties:

```
share name: stuff
Allow others to create and delete files in this folder is cheeked
Guest access (for people without a user account) is checked
```

permissions:

```
Owner: user A
Folder Access: Create and delete files
File Access: ---

Group: user A
Folder Access: Create and delete files
File Access: ---

Others   
Folder Access: Create and delete files
File Access: ---
```

I am at a loss and need to get this work. Any ideas?

The goal is to have a setup like this.  3 users on window machines.  Each user on the data drive will have their own personal folder where they are the ones that can only access, then another folder where 2 of the users will have read only  and one user full access.

I had this setup before on windows, but after what happened I am NEVER going back to windows, so Unix here I am to stay!

I am really stuck.  I am running Ubuntu 11.  I could reformat again and put on version 10 if that would make life easier.  I have been dealing with this since Wed. 3pm.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried by IP? \\192.168.0.10\share? If that works, the problem is narrowed to WINS.

Comment: Same issue.  I think it is a permission things on the unix side.

Comment: whats the exact error message you're getting? What are the logfiles saying (/var/log/samba/*)?

Answer (score 4):

[Name Resolution with Samba](http://oreilly.com/openbook/samba/book/ch07_03.html)

I had the same problem with windows 7 
To fix it All i had to do was change smb.conf

In terminal run

```
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Then change

```
wins support = no

name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
```

To

```
wins support = yes

name resolve order = wins lmhosts host bcast
```

Then restart samba

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: mine doesn't have `name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast`.  is this outdated?

Comment: It is from March 11 2012. It probably is outdated

Answer (score 1):

that could happen if shared folder resides on FAT32 volume (e.g. flash card) and Ubuntu can't add permissions for samba to check. I'm not sure what is the right way to define access rights in that case but simple workaround is to move folder to ext4 volume and share it from there.